# How the app stop when i choose the image from gallery

Tags: android

Now days i try to make a app for photo upload app.

Today I succeed to re upload the image file after i upload the image.

But there was a big problem.

The problem is here

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4. (I couldn't upload the last image file because of upload capacity of this site)

This is the circumstances. when I push the Button for re upload a image, the main Activity Thread just read the next code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

String title = photolist.get(position).getTv_title();
String content = photolist.get(position).getTv_word();
Uri uri = photolist.get(position).changePhotoUri(change_Uri);

photoInfo dict = new photoInfo(uri, title, content);
photolist.set(position, dict);

myAdpayer.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Before when i choose the image of gallery.

So the `ImageView` changed default image like green grid view(3 picture). So when I choose re upload button again then the activity move gallery and then put the back page screen button and then the `ImageView` screen change the Image when i chose before.....

How can I deal with this problem?? I just want to change the Image from gallery just one time...

Here is the code.

Main activity

```
btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//when push this button i move the gallery to pick a image 
    //photo upload first
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);

        title = edit_photo_title.getText().toString();
        content = edit_phto_content.getText().toString();
        dialog.dismiss();


    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: //first image pick 
            imageUri = data.getData();
            photolist.add(new photoInfo(imageUri, "Title : " + title, "Content : " + content));
            mRecycler.setAdapter(myAdpayer);
            break;

        case 2:

            try {// reupload the image
                change_Uri = data.getData();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And then the problem code but here is also main Activity 
because I bring the button from Adapter by using interface.

```
    myAdpayer.setOnItemClickListener(new photoAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, final int position) {


            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu2, popupMenu.getMenu());

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu3:   //reupload button id
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);


                            String title = photolist.get(position).getTv_title();
                            String content = photolist.get(position).getTv_word();
                            Uri uri = photolist.get(position).changePhotoUri(change_Uri);

                            photoInfo dict = new photoInfo(uri, title, content);
                            photolist.set(position, dict);

                            myAdpayer.notifyItemChanged(position);

                            break;
```

Anybody please help me who know a solution T^T;;; and I am sorry my bad English....

Comment: you mean the image remain the first image after you reupload ?

Comment: No it eventually change the image that i chose. but it need two time activity cycle. First when i chose the image the image change the default like green grid image, and then if i chose reupload button again then the activity move the gallery acticity, then that time if i put the backscreen button which there is on the phone, the image change that i chose first for reupload